# Scala Streams and filtering

Tags: scala, stream, scala-collections

I have been learning about using Steams instead of lists in Scala for certain scenarios and this seemingly classic scenario has come up in numerous texts:

Suppose we want to find the second prime number in the range 1 to 10000

If we do the following: 1 to 10000 filter(isPrime)(1)

then we are forced to build the entire list of primes within the interval, and only then take the second element from the list.

However, if we use a stream and delay computation of the tail till only when we need it, then we only have to find the first two primes in the range and then can stop our search through the rest of the range.

My question is: How does Scala know that I am only looking for the second prime? Why wouldn't Scala evaluate the expression left to right, then find the second element of the stream? It seems there is a potential for an out of bounds exception if the index call is applied too early, before the stream has calculated enough primes.

I'm sure the compiler somehow translates the expression to take into account the user only wants the element at index = (1), but I'm curious how this actually takes place "under the hood".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `stream(1)` is equivalent to `stream.drop(1).head`.

That is, the index call is not a look-up in an array where value may or may not be yet. It is actually discarding all elements from the first one until the requested one, as it is done in `List`, or any `LinearSeqOptimized` for that matter.

Comment: ah, so two streams are created. one with [s.head,?] and one with [s.drop(1).head,?]

Comment: Yes. But that's also the case for lists.

Comment: but in the list case the question mark would not be there, hence we save computation time on the tail of the list

Comment: No, because the list will be computed at instantiation, while the stream is computed at call only. Remember that `List(1, 2, 3)` is actually `Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))`, so you have created as many lists as you have elements in your top one.

Comment: i actually had a typo in my most recent comment. I mean we save computation on the tail of the STREAM

Comment: Yes, indeed with stream, we don't compute the tail if it's no needed, that's the whole point.